# Обновление php7.0 на 7.1

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, apache2

Я поставил `php 7.1`, удалил директорию с `7.0`. Если в терминале пишу `php -v`, то пишет `7.1`, но если в программе пишу `phpinfo()`, то выдаёт версию `7.0`. Где указать, чтоб смотрело на `7.1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По идее, чтобы заработал PHP 7.1 вместе с Apache надо убедиться, что установлен пакет [libapache2-mod-php7.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/libapache2-mod-php7.1) и включен модуль mod_php7.1. Следующий набор команд должен всё настроить автоматически*.

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.1
sudo a2enmod php7.1
sudo a2dismod php7.0  # нужно ли?
```

Последняя команда на всякий случай отключает модуль Apache с предыдущей версией PHP, дабы не было непредвиденных конфликтов. Пока я не уверен точно, нужна ли она, или можно обойтись без неё.

* Предполагается, что вы не отключали загрузку настроек модулей в глобальном файле конфигурации `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

Comment: сработало, спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Нужно настроить сам веб-сервер, чтобы загружал нужную версию `php`. А как настроить, это уже зависит от того как используется `php`.

Comment: вот как пример решения: https://superuser.com/questions/971867/why-is-the-php-version-different-in-phpinfo-and-cli

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/205279)

Comment: @maxkrasnov в решении изменяются настройки в httpd.conf, но у меня его нет

Comment: как указал @mymedia, как настроен ваш веб-сервер? что используете?

Comment: @maxkrasnov использую apache2.

Comment: @maxkrasnov в phpinfo() пишет путь `Configuration File (php.ini) Path  /etc/php/7.0/apache2` хотя по сути такого нет

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич, у вас установлен пакет [libapache2-mod-php7.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/libapache2-mod-php7.1)?

Comment: @mymedia да, установлен

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич а вот такого файла нет `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`? нужно в настройках апача добавить новый путь

Comment: @maxkrasnov такой есть, но я делаю поиск по файлу и по имени php ничего не находит. И как добавить новый путь?

Comment: там скорее всего много подключений, попробуй в самом внизу определить переменную `PHPINIDir` с указанием пути к твоей новой папке с `php`, типа: `PHPINIDir "/path/php"`

Comment: @maxkrasnov прописал в конце файла `PHPINIDir "/etc/php/7.1"` и перезагрузил апач. Не сработало(

Comment: @maxkrasnov спасибо большое за помощь )